# Organic Group Content type name

Tags: organic-groups

I am using the Organic Groups module and am following the readme file. I am on step 2:

> Create a new content type via admin/structure/types/add. Call it
>   "Group", and define it to be of Group type.

Just curious, can I call it another name rather than " Group"? like "Site", or something else...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can call it whatever you want. It's a regular [content type](https://drupal.org/glossary#content-type) like any other, i.e Page, News, Event, Blog post, etc.

Perhaps this will help: [Absolute Beginner's Guide to Organic Groups (OG)](https://drupal.org/node/861418)

Cheers,